# after successful porting app is not taking touches/taps on cocos2d buttons

Tags: apportable

After i had successfully  ported the app. the app is running fine and taking touches on native ios nibs files where used for dialogs. But it is not taking touches on menu items.

let me explain this. It has some different view of axis. like tap on somewhere on screen will open some other menu which was not tapped. it seems it is taking touches but opening the desired menus but the location of buttons are not proper..

Answer (score 0):

I had similar. In my case I had implementation of touchesBegan,touchesMoved and touchesEnd in View class with calling super. On iOS it works fine and messages going directly to controller. With apportable SDK it does not work. Maybe you have the same situation.

Comment: what does that mean? Do those overrides need to call the super method?